# Reusing django templates?

Tags: django, django-templates

I find django's template language very limiting. Following along with django's DRY principle, I have a template that I'd like to use in many other templates. For example a patient list:

```
    {% for physician in physicians.all %}
        {% if physician.service_patients.count %}
            <div id="tabs-{{ forloop.counter }}">
                {% include "hospitalists/patient_list.html" %}
            </div>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
```

The problem is that the patient_list template is expecting a list of patients named `patients`. How can I rename `physician.service_patients` to `patients` before including the template?

Thanks,
Pete

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use the with tag:

```
{% for physician in physicians.all %}
   {% if physician.service_patients.count %}
      {% with physician.service_patients as patients %}                   
         <div id="tabs-{{ forloop.counter }}">
            {% include "hospitalists/patient_list.html" %}
         </div>
      {% endwith %}
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

You might also upgrade to creating a custom tag:

```
{% for physician in physicians.all %}
   {% if physician.service_patients.count %}
      {% patient-list physician.service_patients %}
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Although custom tags involve writing Python code, there are shortcuts that make it easy to use an existing template file as a tag: [Django Inclusion Tags](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags)

Comment: Thank you! I kept searching for an "as" tag. I guess "with" works too.

Comment: As of Django 1.3 you can also use the style: `{% include "sometemplate.html" with spam=eggs, ham="Ham!" %}`.

Answer (score 3):

When you have "functionality" (specifically an if-condition) inside a loop, you have an opportunity to move this into the view function.

**First**

This construct

```
{% for physician in physicians.all %}
    {% if physician.service_patients.count %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Is so common that you have several ways to avoid it.

1. Change your model.  Add a `patients" method and use it instead of the default query set that you get with a on-to-many relationship.  This method of your model has the`if service_patients.count` test, removing it from your template.

   This eliminates the {% if %} from your template, reducing it to {% for %} and the actual HTML, which cannot easily the eliminated.
2. Change your view function.  Write a few lines of code to create a list of physicians with service_patients instead of a simplistic collection of physicians.  This code in your view function has the `if service_patients.count` test, removing it from your template.

   This eliminates the {% if %} from your template, reducing it to a {% for %} and the actual HTML, which cannot easily be eliminated.

The point is to get rid of the {% if %} so that you're simply cutting and pasting the {% for %} and the actual HTML.  By keeping your template to just the HTML (which cannot be eliminated), the only overhead is the {% for %}

**Second**

It appears that you want to reuse an `{% include %}` construct in slightly different contexts.

It's not at all clear what the problem with this `{% include %}` file is.  It is "expecting a list of patients named `patients`" seems superficially silly.  Fix it, so it expects `physician.patients`.

Perhaps you want to use this same list twice.  Once with a list called `'patients'` and once with a list called `'physician.patients'`.  In this case, consider (a) simplifying or (b) writing a template tag.

It appears that you have a patient list that is sometimes a stand-alone page, and other times is repeated many times on a much more complex page.  Repeating a list of details embedded in some longer list is not really the best page design.  Django doesn't help you with this because -- frankly -- it's not easy for people to use.  Hence option (a) -- consider redesigning this "patient list within a physician" list as too complex.

However, you can always write a template tags to create really complex pages.

**Summary**

There's a really good reason why the Django template language has limited functionality.  All of your functionality should be either an essential feature of your model, or a feature of the current application that uses the model.

Presentation is simply the translation of objects (and querysets) into HTML.  Nothing more

Comment: S.Lott, I'm not sure how this even remotely answers my question about reusing my template that is expecting an object named patients.

Comment: Can you please elaborate since I'm still in the dark?

Comment: S.Lott, thanks for the clarification. When coupled with something like jQuery UI's tabbed interface, repeating the same template in a more complex context becomes very usable. The with tag is the correct solution to my question.

Comment: Repeating the same template in a more complex context is bad for users.  Creating complex tags to make a more complex UI is bad for users.  Adding complexity in any form is bad for users.

Comment: S.Lott, I'm afraid you're mistaken. Reusing a template is essential to  nearly all web developers. django documentation encourages it. Let me get this straight, you're encouraging duplicating a template and modifying it to expect different parameter names?

Comment: Different parameter names should not occur; your view function prevents this situation. If you think you need variant parameters, you're doing something too complex.

Answer (score 1):

As way, you can try to use in quality templating language [jinja](http://jinja.pocoo.org/2/documentation/). It is more flexible.

Comment: I'm beginning to believe that django's templating engine is so limiting that it should just be thrown away as well.